# Given two points, how do I draw a line through them?

Tags: math, canvas, vector, line

Say I have {x:10, y:20} and {x:100, y:40}, if I wanted to draw a line that starts at 10,20 and ends at 100,40 I'd do:

```
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(10, 20);
 context.lineTo(100, 40);
 context.stroke();
```

But what do I do if I want to draw a line through them? That is the line is longer then the space between the points but it crosses over both points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "inverse" interpolation - by that I mean instead of interpolate a line with a fraction of [0.0, 1.0] you can use a negative value or value > 1 to get "outside" the line:

From **[this online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/23MrF/)**:

[image]

The code is simple, you use the x and y set and interpolate them with a delta, here a fractional value between 0 and 1 where 1 is double length outside one of the points:

```
function extLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, delta) {

    var ox1 = x1 + (x2 - x1) * -delta,
        ox2 = x1 + (x2 - x1) * (1 + delta),
        oy1 = y1 + (y2 - y1) * -delta,
        oy2 = y1 + (y2 - y1) * (1 + delta);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(ox1, oy1);
    ctx.lineTo(ox2, oy2);

    /// for the demo a couple of markers for the original points        
    ctx.rect(x1 - 2, y1 - 2, 5, 5);
    ctx.rect(x2 - 2, y2 - 2, 5, 5);

    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Instead of a fraction as delta you could calculate the length of the line and then get a fraction from that result so you'll you extend the line in numbers of pixels instead.

Here is a version where you give number of pixels instead:

```
function extLine2(x1, y1, x2, y2, pixels) {

    /// calc fraction based on line length and added pixels        
    var xd = x2 - x1,
        yd = y2 - y1,
        len = Math.sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd),
        delta = pixels / len,

        /// as before
        ox1 = x1 + (x2 - x1) * -delta,
        ox2 = x1 + (x2 - x1) * (1 + delta),
        oy1 = y1 + (y2 - y1) * -delta,
        oy2 = y1 + (y2 - y1) * (1 + delta);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(ox1, oy1);
    ctx.lineTo(ox2, oy2);

    ctx.rect(x1 - 2, y1 - 2, 5, 5);
    ctx.rect(x2 - 2, y2 - 2, 5, 5);

    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Draw a longer line, using one of several alternatives:

1. Intersect the line with the boundaries of the canvas to obtain endpoints
2. Intersect the line with the “more orthogonal” canvas boundaries, i.e. if the absolute value of the x difference is less than that of the y difference, intersect with the bottom and top boundary, otherwise with the vertical boundary lines
3. Extend the line by a fixed and sufficiently large multiple of the difference vector
4. Extend the line by such a multiple of the difference vector that this extension is of fixed and known size

Which of these is most appropriate depends on your application. Can you rely on a maximal canvas size, or a minimal point distance? If not, then the intersection alternatives are more robust, with the second one being less work.